# Trouble making a Firebase query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble implementing an endless scroll in android using a recycler view. What I want is, essentially, something like instagram, that you scroll through a page endlessly.

I have a Firebase database with 10 items, and I want to show 3 items and charge the next two, then when you scroll through the next two items start loading the next 5 and so on. (You will see that most of this in the example is hardcoded).

I am having trouble making a Firebase query like this:

```
myRef.orderByChild("id").startAt(page*5 + "").endAt(5+page*5 + "")
```

what I would like to get then is at my current location the next 5 items with and id between - let's say - 5 and 10. However, when I do this:

```
    myRef.orderByChild("id").startAt(page*5 + "").endAt(5+page*5 + "")
            .getRef().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(i == 5) break;
                mDataset.add(postSnapshot.getValue(Card.class));
                i++;
            }

            mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mDataset);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

all the postSnapshots return ids 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Making the illusion of scrolling endlessly but charging the same 5 items every time.

Thanks

Edit:

EndlessScrollListener

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    private int mVisibleThreshold = 2,
            mCurrentPage = 0,
            mPreviousTotalItemCount = 0,
            mStartingPageIndex = 0;

    private boolean mLoading = true;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public EndlessScrollListener(){}

    public EndlessScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager){
        mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold){
        mVisibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions){
        int maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; ++i){
            if(lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize)
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy){
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0,
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

        if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition =
                    ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        if(totalItemCount < mPreviousTotalItemCount){
            mCurrentPage = mStartingPageIndex;
            mPreviousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            mLoading = totalItemCount == 0;
        }

        if(mLoading && totalItemCount > mPreviousTotalItemCount){
            mLoading = false;
            mPreviousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        if(!mLoading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + mVisibleThreshold) > totalItemCount){
            mCurrentPage++;
            onLoadMore(mCurrentPage, totalItemCount, view);
            mLoading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);

    public void resetState(){
        mCurrentPage = mStartingPageIndex;
        mPreviousTotalItemCount = 0;
        mLoading = true;
    }
}
```

In its activity

```
scrollListener = new EndlessScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            System.out.println("Dale... Page: " + page + " items: " + totalItemsCount);

            loadData(page);
        }
    };
```

Comment: How do you determine `page`?

Comment: @Drew page gets determined through a scrollLlistener going up everytime (lastVisibleItemPosition + mVisibleThreshold) > totalItemCount

Comment: Thanks @Levon, could you please update your original post with the ScrollListener? The complete code will make it easier to determine the issue.

Comment: There you go @Drew